# Rails Resque change worker limit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background, redis, resque, worker

I have Rails app with some Resque workers. It seems that I have a limit of 2 workers running simultaneously (app runs on EC2 with Apache in production). Is there any way I can raise that limit?

EDIT:

I have maxclients 0 in redis.conf

I can start 10 workers through rake, but when they are actually getting queued, I get "ERR max number of clients reached" in browser..

EDIT: updated mistake (it was correct in original file)

EDIT: actually had config/initializers/Resque.rb pointing to redis-to-go (was rudiment from the early days of app), once I removed that, pointing to config/resque.yml (with localhost) everything went to normal and I can start as many workers as I please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe your question is more of a sysadmin one, but if not a system resource issue, then this may help.
from http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque?view=asciicast

Using the resque gem, just use this rake task

```
#/lib/tasks/resque.rake 
require "resque/tasks"

task "resque:setup" => :environment
```

and start up as many resque workers as you need.

```
$ rake resque:work QUEUE='*'
```

best use some service monitoring framework, svc, monit, god. and use resque web.

Comment: the problem I am getting into is "ERR max number of clients reached" any time I try to exceed 3 workers. I tried setting up maxclients in redis.conf to a large number, but no good.. What can it be related to? I am using the approach you are mentioning in development and the result is pretty much the same.

Comment: this error is defo about redis connections limit. try maxclients with 0 (no limit), or tag your question with redis including your redis conf maybe.

Comment: did the maxclients 0 and now can start more workers.. I thought that answers the question, but I tried the server and get ERR max number of clients reached in browser.. updated the question. Thanks for help though!

Comment: I figured the error (updated the question), but I guess, I will choose this as an answer, since it pointed towards maxclients etc..