# How do I assign one worker to a queu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, resque

In Resque, if I have the following:

```
bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE=critical,high,normal,low,aggregate
```

How do I indicate that I only want one, and ONLY ONE worker, for a specific queue (i.e. the aggregate queue)?

Comment: you may probably check this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859250/rails-resque-change-worker-limit

Comment: Did you down vote? What about that question? Did you read it before suggesting the link? Different context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont think that is possible

Reason if you look the current code over [here](https://github.com/defunkt/resque/blob/master/lib/resque/multi_queue.rb#L51)

Resque poll all the queue

```
value = @redis.blpop(*(queue_names + [1])) until value
```

where queue_names is your `critical,high,normal,low,aggregate`

so the point over here Irrespective you if you use single resque work or mutilple workers

using `resque:workers` each of the resque work poll all the available queue and once the

message is consumed from any on the queue the work start acting upon it

If you want to assign only one work for the above queue it would be better running two rake

task like this

`bundle exec rake resque:worker COUNT=4 QUEUE=critical,high,normal,low`

`bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE=aggregate`

This way you can assign a single resque worker for the `aggregate` queue

Hope this help

Comment: shouldn't it be `bundle exec rake resque:work COUNT=1 QUEUE=aggregate` ?

Comment: `resque:work` will start only 1 work whereas `resque:workers` will start `n` workers based on the `count` supplied check over here `https://github.com/defunkt/resque/blob/master/lib/resque/tasks.rb`